# How can I get an enemy to shoot bullets at a player using SpriteKit no matter where the player moves to inside the view?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I have a game with a sprite called enemy which has an invisible circle around it and a player sprite that can move freely 360 degrees around the enemy. When the player enters the frame of the enemy's circle however, this triggers the enemy to begin shooting bullets at the player. The player can still move. The problems I am having is with keeping the enemy continuously shooting the bullets as well as continuously firing them toward the position of the player even after the player has changed locations.

I will add some code to help you checkout the problem:

For fast reference we have this short piece here where i included only the minimum of what I thought was necessary for fast help. (I am not sure where to call the fireBullets() function... Inside the update function? Inside of did move? Inside of didBegin?).

```
    func fireBullets() {

        var fireBulletAction: SKAction

        fireBulletAction = SKAction.run {
            let bullet = self.createBullets()
            var moveBullet = SKAction.move(to: self.player.position, duration: 1)
            bullet.run(moveBullet)
        }

        var waitForDuration: SKAction
        waitForDuration = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)

        var bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([fireBulletAction, waitForDuration])

        var repeatBulletSequence = SKAction.repeatForever(bulletSequence)

        enemy.run(repeatBulletSequence, withKey: "fireBullet")
    }
```

Or to recreate the problem even faster and easier with all components(It's still only 96 lines of code), I made this simple GameScene.swift file which you can easily copy and paste from [text](https://gist.github.com/jnmquick/d2c6b4340de87d17f12820c174938519#file-recreategamescene-swift) into XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I had not considered that you were using `SKAction.repeatForever` in your project, so I've edited my original answer which was partly wrong.

This is your problem:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // side note: add this when overriding methods
    super.didMove(to: view)

    createPlayer(view: view)
    createEnemy(view: view)
    if collisionDetected {
        fireBullets()
    }
}
```

This method is called when the scene is presented. And in your sample project at that point `collisionDetected` is `false`, so `fireBullets()` will never trigger.

You should move it inside the `update()` function, which is called once every 1/60 seconds, assuming your fps setting is 60. Note: I'm also assuming you don't want to locate the player and the enemy such that the shooting is triggered as soon as the scene is presented:

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        super.update(currentTime)
        if !collisionDetected {
            detectCollisions()
        } else if !isShooting {
            fireBullets()
        }
    }
```

Note that I've added a `isShooting` check, it's a new variable. The reason of it is that, since you're using `SKAction.repeatForever` and `update()` is called multiple times, you want to trigger the `fireBullets()` method just once. A way to achieve this is to declare indeed another variable to keep track of it.

```
var isShooting = false
```

Then in `fireBullets()` you set it to true as soon as it is fired for the first time, so that it will not be fired again:

```
isShooting = true
```

If you wanna read more about it, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498796/holding-down-a-button-in-spritekits-gcvirtualcontroller/76553311#76553311) is another similar example, from a question I answered.

This way in your sample project everything works as intended, at least in my simulator, as per what you have stated.

On a side node, you should remove the bullet nodes from the scene at some point, I suppose you actually take care of this in your actual project, otherwise the node count will skyrocket up untill a crash.

Also, for collision detection consider using `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`. You could handle the `fireBullets()` call there.

Comment: Hey so I have tried this exact solution, however the only problem is that calling fireBullets() in the update function like you suggested is causing the bullets to be created much more rapidly than the 1 second intervals defined in my wait(for: duration) SKAction being ran in the sequence. I also tried using similar logic in the touches began stating if collisionDetected { fireBullets() } Sadly this only works if the screen is touched again after the collisionDetected becomes true.

Comment: I've edited the answer a few minutes ago, indeed I had skipped the fact that you were repeating the action forever. Check it out my edited answer now, it should be good.

Comment: The edited solution works.

Comment: Another issue I'm seeing now, you're not calling super when overriding methods. I think you should do it, I'm gonna edit my answer once more.

Comment: Could you explain a little more why you think I should call super here? Im not sure that it is necessary in this case when overriding the parent method. Thanks

Comment: It's not necessary but not "harmful" also for what you want to achieve in your project. And the best practice is to always call super, unless you need to disable functionalities in the base class. However, maybe me saying "issue" was misleading, not an issue just a good practice. I'm sorry but, as you can probably tell, english is not my native language. Hope you got the point now

Comment: I will add the super calls if it doesn't cause any harm. Just for good practice

Comment: I ran into another problem a couple minutes ago, if you wouldn't mind taking a look when you aren't busy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674774/how-can-i-complete-the-action-of-an-skaction-move-where-the-object-being-moved-i

Comment: Now that I see that you are indeed using PhysicsContactDelegate, consider moving fireBullets() there, it’s better than in update().

Comment: Should I move it to didBeginContact? or didSimulatePhysics?